# Tabulator: Is there a way to have the HeaderFilter use the Formatted Values rather than the Raw Data Values

Tags: tabulator

I have a tabulator table with a column containing DateTimeOffsetValues e.g.
'2020-01-07T13:23:00.000 +01:00', which are being formatted using the builtin DateTime format.

The column works fine displaying the data, but when using the HeaderFiltering, all of the values are the raw data values.

Is there a simple way to have the values supplied to the HeaderFiltering use the Formatted values ? I haven't found anything in the documentation for applying a formatter to autogenerated headerfilter values, but i could be missing something.

I have included the column definition below:

```
 {
    "field": "AuditDate",
    "title": "Audit Date",
    "visible": true,
    "formatter": "datetime",
    "formatterParams": {
      "inputFormat": null,
      "outputFormat": "DD/MM/YYYY",
      "invalidPlaceholder": null
    },
    "headerFilter": "autocomplete",
    "headerFilterParams": {
      "allowEmpty": true,
      "showListOnEmpty": true,
      "values": true,
      "multiselect": true
    },
    "headerSort": true,
    "editor": "",
    "editorOptions": null,
    "position": 41,
    "cellClick": function (e,row) {auditDateCellClick ( e, row ); }
  }
```

Comment: Deleted my answer as I realized I was misreading the question. I know of no way to have ```"values"``` come up in formatted form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either create a [Custom Formatter](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/format#format-custom) to behave in the way you want.

Or you could look at using a [Mutator](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/mutators#mutators) instead of a formatter. this would change the underlying data, instead of just the way it appears, allowing you to filter it that way